# Using multidimenshional array in an editable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, contenteditable, each

I am using steps in a editable div.Each step may contain different elements like span,div etc.I want to store all the  steps and thier elements or content with same class in the database.

**Approach,I have used**
Firstly I gathered the content  having same class in  every step  and then I have tried to place the steps and  thier content into array via .each loop.but it did not work

```
<div  id="txtarea2" contenteditable="true">
<div class="stepo1"><span  class="spannumber" id="1">1 </span> :
    <span id="1" class="steps3 ">yahhhjjjjjjjjasdfasdf</span></div>
<div class="stepo1"><span class="steps3 " >asdfasdfasdfasdf</span></div>
<br>

<div class="stepo2"><span class="spannumber" id="2">2 </span> :
    <span id="2" class="steps3 " >yahhhadfasdfasdf</span></div>
<br>
```

answer

javascript goes here.

```
    function add_to_answer(){
           var  values=[];
            $('.steps3').each(function(i,el){
           values.push(el.id.$('.stepo'+el.id).text());
            });
   alert(values);
   }
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/younis764/Hv92k/)  goes here.

Plz help me or suggest any alternative approach.

Comment: `el.id.$('.stepo'+el.id)` doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 function add_to_answer(){

       var  values=[];

       $('.steps3').each(function(){
          var xTemp = [];
          xTemp[xTemp.length] = $(this).attr('id');
          xTemp[xTemp.length] = $('.stepo'+ $(this).attr('id')).text();

          values[values.length] = xTemp;
          xTemp = [];
       });

       alert(JSON.stringify(values));

   }
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hv92k/3/)

Comment: Thank you,and how will I get the separte values for each step in php?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to point out:

You can simply call $(this).text() within the loop

JS:

```
function add_to_answer(){
   var  values=[];
   $('.steps3').each(function(){
       values.push($(this).parent().find('.spannumber').text());
   });
   alert(values);
}
```

Also, I wouldn use an unobtrusive approach to calling a function. 
answer

JS:

```
//bind on dom ready
$(function() {

    //bind click event 
    $('#answer').on('click', function() {

       var  values=[];
       $('.steps3').each(function(){
           values.push($(this).parent().find('.spannumber').text());
       });

      //do something with `values`

    });
});
```

Link to fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8N7Ez/

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thank you.it is combining all values of all the steps.I want to get different values for every step like div#stepo1,div#stepo2,div#stepo3 etc